# Pass Byte as SmallInt?

Tags: sql, vb.net, stored-procedures, informix

I have an Informix stored procedure which takes an int and a "smallint" as parameters. I'm trying to call this SP from a .net4 Visual Basic program.

As far as I know, "smallint" is a byte. Unfortunately, when loading up the IfxCommand.Parameters collection with an Integer and a Byte, I get an ArgumentException thrown of `{"The parameter data type of Byte is invalid."}` with the following stack trace:

> at IBM.Data.Informix.TypeMap.FromObjectType(Type dataType, Int32 length)
>      at IBM.Data.Informix.TypeMap.FromObjectType(Type dataType)
>      at IBM.Data.Informix.IfxParameter.GetTypeMap()
>      at IBM.Data.Informix.IfxParameter.GetOutputValue(IntPtr stmt, CNativeBuffer valueBuffer, CNativeBuffer lenIndBuffer)
>      at IBM.Data.Informix.IfxDataReader.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
>      at IBM.Data.Informix.IfxDataReader.System.IDisposable.Dispose()
>      at IBM.Data.Informix.IfxCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
>      at IBM.Data.Informix.IfxCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at IBM.Data.Informix.IfxCommand.ExecuteReader()

Presumably I need to cast the Byte I have to a smallint, somehow, but google isn't giving me any relevant answers, just at the moment.

I have tried using:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(New IfxParameter("myVal", IBM.Data.Informix.IfxType.SmallInt)).Value = myByte
```

but I still get the same ArgumentException when executing the reader.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `Byte` is a bit like a UInt8 and has no sign, have you tried `short` or `Int16`?

Comment: Well, evidently everyone at my company who thinks that an Informix smallint is a byte is wrong. I hadn't actually considered that possibility...

Comment: Re: my previous comment, please don't confuse my hypothetical UInt8 with the informix Int8 which is actually more like a .Net Long or Int64 and, please don't forget to mark or upvote the answers if they are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Informix [SmallInt](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.ddi.doc/ddi62.htm) is a 16 bit signed integer, `byte` is an 8 bit unsigned integer. A better equivalent would be `Int16` or `Short` which is a 16 bit signed integer, just like SmallInt. I suspect that will work.

Informix has no analogue for an unsigned 8 bit integer like the .Net `Byte` or the TSQL `TinyInt`.

Answer (score 1):

Int16 should work since it has the same range than SmallInt (-32,767 to 32,767)

Answer (score 1):

Informix has 4 types that are related: BYTE and TEXT (since 1990), BLOB and CLOB (since 1996).  Collectively, they are all large objects.  A BYTE type is absolutely *NOT* a small integer type.

You may be able to use BYTE in a language that thinks it is a small integer if the language or driver fixes up the types.

But the native BYTE type is a large object.  It requires a 56-byte descriptor in the main row of data, and then uses other storage (possibly IN TABLE, possibly in a blobspace) for the actual data storage.